# "Adrenaline-filled" or "Adrenaline-fuelled"

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct in the following instance - *"adrenaline-filled"* or *"adrenaline-fuelled"*?

> A surfing trip is often an adrenaline-filled/fuelled holiday.

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adrenaline-fuelled%2Cadrenaline-filled&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadrenaline%20-%20fuelled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadrenaline%20-%20filled%3B%2Cc0) indicates that 'filled' is the more common expression, but both are in use.

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid uses, but they have different meanings.

> A surfing trip is often an adrenaline-filled holiday.

Here, you're suggesting the holiday is *full* of lots of vigorous, heart-pumping activities (namely, surfing). It's a bit ironic, too, because you likely won't have a moment's rest!

> A surfing trip is often an adrenaline-fueled holiday.

This suggests the trip is *motivated* or *driven* by adrenaline (or rather, by your *love of adrenaline*). For example, if you're a thrill seeker, then your desire for adrenaline-inducing activities would fuel (motivate) that "holiday".

Comment: But "-fuelled" could also mean "energised" by something as well as caused (or motivated) by something - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fuelled_2

Comment: Yep, certainly. In this case, by "motivated", I don't just mean the *initial* motivation. Here, "motivation" encompasses both the initial desire to pursue something as well as the ongoing desire.

Answer (score 0):

They are both potentially correct.

Adrenaline is popularly believed to be released by the body **as a result of** exciting activities, so an adrenaline-filled holiday would be one in which many exciting activities were experienced.

The verb 'fuel' means to provide energy, to stimulate or encourage, so strictly speaking an adrenaline-fuelled holiday would be one which was made possibly by the taking of adrenaline as a drug. Compare alcohol-fuelled violence, drug-fuelled orgies. In spite of this, you will see plenty of advertisements for "adrenaline-fuelled holidays" by companies offering white-water rafting, bungee-jumping, jet-ski rides, etc.

A possibly necessary note is that **adrenaline** is a natural hormone secreted by the human body during "fight or flight" moments, whereas **Adrenalin** is the name of a synthetic medical product (containing adrenaline) by the Parke-Davis drug company. The product is called Epinephrine in the USA.